# Could not find method makeScaleUpAnimation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, android-animation

I am using makeScaleUpAnimation in my project like below, (in a fragment)

```
ActivityOptions options = 
    ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(v, 0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
getActivity().startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

The project is building successfully but in runtime I had that error:

```
 I/dalvikvm(5432): Could not find method 
android.app.ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation, referenced from method
 com.example.webapicaller.ui.fragment.ImageGridFragment.onItemClick
```

But I can found that method in the project's android library. 
I couldn't find any reason, please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those methods and classes are included in API level 16. If your targetSDK is >= 16 it will compile, but when trying to run it on a device with a lower Android version, it will crash on runtime.

Comment: You right, Target SDK was 21 and min SDK version was 8 :) my emulator was api 14 also... It was build successfull because the library was 21, but emulator didn't have required version of library. I updated settings to min is 16 and it's working fine now. thanks